# Subquery vs join

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT
    id
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    subject_id = 1 
    OR subject_id IN (
        SELECT related_subject_id 
        FROM RelatedSubjects
        WHERE parent_subject_id = 1);
```

Trying to select all posts for a current subject but also for any sub-subjects which are stored in another lookup table. The above query works, wondering how to accomplish the same thing with a join

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM Posts AS p
LEFT JOIN RelatedSubjects AS r 
ON p.subject_id = r.related_subject_id AND r.parent_subject_id = 1
WHERE p.subject_id = 1 OR r.related_subject_id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming proper indexes, `UNION` often performs better than `JOIN` with `OR`:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Posts AS p
WHERE p.subject_id = 1
UNION
SELECT p.id
FROM RelatedSubjects AS r 
JOIN Posts AS p
ON p.subject_id = r.related_subject_id
WHERE r.parent_subject_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    `Posts`.`id`
From posts as `Posts`
LEFT join RelatedSubjects as `RelatedSubjects`
on (`RelatedSubjects`.`related_subject_id` = `Posts`.`subject_id`)
where `Posts`.`subject_id` = 1
```